# Own Server Without ISP

Tags: isp, dyndns

Is there any way I could host my own server but without my ISP? A few reasons why I want this are:

- No bandwidth limit
- Allowed to have unlimited traffic
- No complaints about the content of my site from the ISP

I also want a static ip so I wouldn't have to use dynamic dns'.

Comment: This is a big ask, I'm going to keep an eye on this for responses. You basically want to set up your own ISP? Or host a webserver?

Comment: How do you intend to connect your server to the Internet without an ISP?

Comment: @tombull89: [Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/10043/wiki-irritating-phrases-you-are-subjected-to-in-the-enterprise/10113#10113). :)

Comment: come on own up, whats the site's content ?

Comment: @Sirex 10 to one it involves Anime, furries or both!

Comment: @jscott: wow. perhaps I should have replaced "ask" with "question" (and I think the worst phrase is "touch base")

Comment: replace it with "This is a tall order". :)

Comment: In some ways I hate the reply I'm about to give, but sometimes it is entirely appropriate, as it is now: *If you have to ask, then you can't/shouldn't. This is very far from being a trivial exercise.*

Answer (score 4):

Rent a virtual private server.  If that's not enough for your needs, rent a managed host.  IF you want to run everything yourself, buy a 1U server, install what you want on it, and buy some colocation space for it.

Comment: Even with a colo'ed server, it's very unlikely that all three of Neb's (far-fetched) requirements will be met.

Comment: My colo doesn't charge extra for bandwidth use.  However, I did get a nasty letter from a copyright troll when one of my users decided to bittorrent something from HBO.

Answer (score 2):

> •No bandwidth limit •Allowed to have
>   unlimited traffic •No complaints about
>   the content of my site from the ISP

Yes, totally easy.

First, make sure all users are connected to you not using the internet. Second, make sure you run the server and your users are in a country where all content is legal or noone else than your agreed upon trustworthy users ever see the content.

This quesiton is STUPID. Seriously. "no bandwidth limit" is like "I need unlimited telephon lines, free of charge, for using however i want". what about "unlimited pizza deliveries for a year for 9.99 USD Once"? No complaints - what you think ISP's complain about? Seriously. ILLEGAL CONTENT: It is not illegal because the ISP complains.

Get real. YOu ned an ISP, because even if you do not have one - how you think the internet works? WIthout ISP... users need to either have a leased line to your server, or dial in via modem.

You will always pay for bandwidth one way or the other because - like pizza - it costs money to have it available. Even ISP's orffering hosting with "unlimited bandwidth" DO limit it - if anything else it is a mixed calculation AND you are limited to the speed of the port. Try asking them to upgrade you to 10 x 10gbit for free.

And unless you and some others change the governments, you will get complaints for illegal content because it is illegal in the first place.

Comment: Oh, I'd imagine some ISPs even do the upgrade to some fat pipe for free.  The upgrade only, mind you...

Answer (score 0):

You will always need an ISP involved unless you plan on creating your own ISP with peering arrangements.  But as my momma always said, if you have to ask...  ;)

The ISP provides connectivity for your systems.  By definition (Internet Service Provider), that's their job.  There are a countless variety of vendors that package connectivity with colocation (space, power, cooling) or some variation thereof.  It sounds to me like you just want to host your server out of your house without the headaches of a consumer ISP.  Unless you live in a very connected area, with incredibly flexible terms of service, I find it highly unlikely.

Your best bet is a colocation service (e.g. Server Central, SAVVIS, etc) that resells colocation space from the big boys (e.g. Equinix).